# Is the rotation of the magnetic force real or just a convention?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

The magnetic force exerted by a moving charge is usually represented as a rotating flux

[image]

Is that just a convention useful to remember the direction of the pull or it is a realistic representation? The fact that is is related to the electric force by v^2/c^2 would imply, on the contrary that propagation takes place as a spherical wave ruled by the inverse square law, with the addition of the sine of the angle.

Can you also explain what happens when the charge (say on wire 1) oscillates back and forth? 
[image]

Is the magnetic force inverting direction of rotation?

Lastly, is EMR due to the varying electric field, as they generally say, or more simply related to speed and direction of the charge on wire1 ?

Comment: See Faraday's paradox, which would imply there is no rotation involved.

Comment: @JohnMeacham, thanks, do you know why that odd representation was chosen?